# firefox flash wmode direct z-index transparency background

Tags: html, css, flash, firefox

I have this issue with Firefox 28 & 29 on **Windows only** (Working on OSX for Chrome, Safari, Firefox and on Windows for IE and Chrome)

I have a html modal box with **a transparent background** and a swf object.
The background stays behind the flash object but the modal content is correctly in front of everything.
If I set my background opacity to 1 it's working fine.

I'm using the **wmode='direct' and I can't change it because of  3d library** which needs to have the wmode to 'direct'

Here is basically what the code looks like:

```
<body>
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="Main" name="Main" align="middle" bgcolor="#fff" data="main.swf" width="100%" height="100%" style="z-index:100;">
        <param name="quality" value="high">
        <param name="bgcolor" value="#fff">
        <param name="wmode" value="direct">
        <param name="flashvars" value="myVars">
    </object>
    <div class="fancybox-overlay fancybox-overlay-fixed" style="background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);z-index:150;">
        <div class="fancybox-wrap fancybox-desktop fancybox-type-ajax fancybox-opened" style="z-index:160;">
            <div class="fancybox-skin">
                <div class="fancybox-outer">
                    <div class="fancybox-inner" >
                        My Modal Box Content
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a title="Close" class="fancybox-item fancybox-close"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Any idea about this one ?

Thanks for your time,

Joris

Comment: will you please post CSS/jsfiddle/page URL it will help to debug code

Comment: Hi, did you ever find a fix for this? I am experiencing exactly the same problem in Firefox/Windows 7 & 8 only. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use HTML-overlay on Flash-object if `wmode` was set to `direct`, `window` or `gpu` values. Flash doesn't support HTML layering in most browsers for these `wmode`.

Take a look at table https://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/flash-object-embed-tag-attributes.html#main_Browser_support_for_Window_Mode__wmode__values

> L = HTML layering is supported. HTML elements can overlap SWF content. Supports explicit control of layering in relation to other HTML elements.